# Button Listener not get registered on first click In android

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

As i am new to android here i got the problem for button listeners
I am using OnClickListener for busttons but it **doesnot performs after first click** once i click more than one it performs well but how to make it possible on first click it self 
here is my code:

```
public class DashbordActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

ImageButton btnLogout, btnSearch, btnOENew, btnAENew,btnSync;
// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashbord_activity);

    // Session Manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    /* Action Bar Color change on create*/
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF7F24"));
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

    /* get Resources from Xml  file */
    btnOENew = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnOENew);
    btnAENew = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAENew);
    btnSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);     
    btnLogout = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
    btnSync = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnSync);

    addButtonListener();// on click any button
}
    // on click any button
private void addButtonListener() {
    // Find our button and hook-up the click routine
    btnOENew.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);     
    btnAENew.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSync.setOnClickListener(this);
}

// on click any button
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    btnOENew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),           OceanSalesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnAENew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AirSalesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            onLogout();
        }
    });

    btnSync.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent( getBaseContext() , SyncActivity.class);                                                
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: if you are asking for clarification pls comment below my post instead of editing my post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you need annonymous inner class when you have

```
 btnOENew.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and your class implements `OnClickListener`

All you need is switch case in `onClick`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId())
     {
       case R.id.btnOENew :
           // button btnOENew clicked
       break;
       case R.id.btnAENew :
            // button btnAENew clicked  
       break;
       ... // similar for other buttons
      }
}
```

Comment: thnk u for u r reply... tht means i should call listeners btnOENew.setOnClickListener(this); directly onCreate m i ryt?

Comment: @AditiK no need for that since you have `addButtonListener();` and this in the method `btnOENew.setOnClickListener(this);` this refers to activity context and in your case your class implements the interface `OnClickListener`. Remove other unwanted code and it should work

Comment: ok ...will implement accordingly ...thnk u so much for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are registering the listeners for the button two times..After first click on the button you again registering button with original listener..Remove all the button onClick methods and change your code like this..

```
// on click any button
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnOENew) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                OceanSalesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnAENew) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AirSalesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSearch) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SearchActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnLogout) {
        onLogout();
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSync) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SyncActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**

> try this

**

```
 public class DashbordActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton btnLogout, btnSearch, btnOENew, btnAENew,btnSync;
// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashbord_activity);

// Session Manager
session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

/* Action Bar Color change on create*/
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF7F24"));
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

/* get Resources from Xml  file */
btnOENew = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnOENew);
btnAENew = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAENew);
btnSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);     
btnLogout = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
btnSync = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnSync);
 btnOENew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),           OceanSalesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

btnAENew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AirSalesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SearchActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});


btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
    public void onClick(View v) {               
        onLogout();
    }
});

btnSync.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( getBaseContext() , SyncActivity.class);                                                
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});



}
```