# Android - Image Buttons cannot be clicked with just a one click

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

I'm currently making an app that contains Image Buttons. However, upon clicking the Image Button, it doesn't trigger an action but when you click the Image Button twice, it will start the Intent.

Below is the code for the activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"></LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:src="@drawable/mainscreen"/>


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gallerylogo2"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/gallerybutton"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"/>
```

Below is the code for the intent:

```
btnGallery = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gallerybutton);
btnGallery.setOnClickListener(goToGallery);

View.OnClickListener goToGallery = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivity(intent);

        /*Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent , RESULT_GALLERY );*/
    }
};
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: which method is used within your listener?

Comment: @bolfredo View.onClickListener

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" why is this relevant to the question?

Comment: @noev because I suspected it's all because of the graphics of my app and it eats alot of memory since one activity is equivalent to 57.072MB

Comment: did you use `android:focusableInTouchMode`

Comment: please post your codes

Comment: I edited my post and added the codes @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: wrong order of your goToGallery. That shouldnt work at all

Comment: How did you say so @bofredo?

Comment: in 2nd line you use a variable that is declared in line 3

Answer (score 1):

Remove `btnGallery.setOnClickListener(goToGallery);`
And

```
btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // Your staff

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

});
```

Comment: using `setOnClickListener`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755322/button-listener-not-get-registered-on-first-click-in-android

Comment: @user5290675 check my answer

Comment: what is `View.OnClickListener` ?

Comment: @user5290675 very strange case

Answer (score 1):

use import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
and use this code instead

```
OnClickListener goToGallery = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivity(intent);

            /*Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,                   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent , RESULT_GALLERY );*/
        }
    };
```